# Looping from an array display a non wanted character with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        "info" => "This is my info",
        "colors" => array(
            "type" => "block",
            array(
                "name" => "Red",
                "ref" => "red"
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Blue",
                "ref" => "blue"
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I want to loop into the `color` array like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item['colors'] as $color) {
        $color['name'];
    }
}
```

The problem, is the first result is `b` from `block`.

How can I change this behavior ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the `name` element exists in the `$color` value:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item['colors'] as $color) {
        if (isset($color['name'])) {
            $name = $color['name'];
            // do something with it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the given array, reference the keys in your first loop to get to `colors` and check if the $value is an array, if it is, then check to see if the array_key `name` is in the array, if it is, you have the value(s) you are looking for.

// assuming you know the array levels design your conditional to check if you have an array - `is_array`, if you do, make sure the target key is `in_array`, if it is, compare the target key with the values `array_keys` and then echo the `value['target_key']`

```php
foreach($items[0]['colors'] as $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        if(in_array('name', array_keys($value))){
            echo $value['name'].'<br>';
        }
    }
}


// slightly more dynamic way to use incrementor, 
// though this assumes you still know the level of 'colors' and 'name'

$i = count($items);
for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
    foreach($items[$j]['colors'] as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            if(in_array('name', array_keys($value))){
                echo $value['name'].'<br>';
            }
        }
    } 
}

// or check each level to see if is array and if target key is in array

$i = count($items);
for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
    foreach($items[$j] as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            if(in_array('colors', array_keys($value))){
                foreach($value as $color){
                    if(is_array($color)){
                        if(in_array('name', array_keys($color))){
                            echo $color['name'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Each iteration will output:

```
Red
Blue
```